# BZ2 compression in C++ with bzlib.h

Tags: c++, bzip2

I currently need some help learning how to use bzlib.h header. I was wondering if anyone would be as so kind to help me figure out a compressToBZ2() function in C++ **without** using any Boost libraries?

```
void compressBZ2(std::string file)
{
  std::ifstream infile;
  int fileDestination = infile.open(file.c_str());

  char bz2Filename[] = "file.bz2";
  FILE *bz2File = fopen(bz2Filename, "wb");
  int bzError;
  const int BLOCK_MULTIPLIER = 7;
  BZFILE *myBZ = BZ2_bzWriteOpen(&bzError, bz2File, BLOCK_MULTIPLIER, 0, 0);

  const int BUF_SIZE = 10000;
  char* buf = new char[BUF_SIZE];
  ssize_t bytesRead;

  while ((bytesRead = read(fileDestination, buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0)
  {
    BZ2_bzWrite(&bzError, myBZ, buf, bytesRead);
  }

  BZ2_bzWriteClose(&bzError, myBZ, 0, NULL, NULL);

  delete[] buf;
}
```

What I've been trying to do is use something like this but I've had no luck. I am trying to get a .bz2 file **not** .tar.bz2

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two lines are wrong:

```
int fileDestination = infile.open(file.c_str());

// ...

while ((bytesRead = read(fileDestination, buf, BUF_SIZE)) > 0)
```

This isn't how [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) works. For example, if you look at [`std::ifstream::open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open) it doesn't return anything. It seems you are mixing up the old system calls `open`/`read` with the C++ stream concept.

Just do:

```
infile.open(file.c_str());

// ...

while (infile.read(buf, BUF_SIZE))
```

I recommend you read up more on using streams.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked perfectly. I figured I did something wrong with the streams as I'm not too familiar with them.

Answer (score 2):

Try with libbzip2.

It's available in C.

https://www.sourceware.org/bzip2

For a code sample see: `dlltest.c`

Comment: Fixed the link as requested.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the loop and it's working.

```
int BUF_SIZE = 1024 * 10;    
char* buf = new char[BUF_SIZE];
while(infile.tellg() >= 0) {
    infile.read(buf, BUF_SIZE);
    BZ2_bzWrite(&bzError, myBZ, buf, infile.gcount());
}    
BZ2_bzWriteClose(&bzError, myBZ, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: This solution works in this context. It is necessary to pass infile.gcount() to BZ2_bzwrite. With the currently accepted solution, one ends up with an empty bz2 file.