# Zip multiple files in C++

Tags: c++

I have created ".tar" file and added multiple files in it while converting  it to ".zip" i am facing problem. 
I should create ".zip" for  compress multiple files.

I need this in c++
 code.[BZ2 compression in C++ with bzlib.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494255/bz2-compression-in-c-with-bzlib-h)  I used this link to compress.

I tryed with http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html   i feel its complicated.

please help me i am new to it Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Can you show (in code) what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have used minizip. It is a good choice in my opinion and you have a sample file that is really helpful (it is mentioned in the link you sent)

Comment: how can i add code to it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have used, Minizip is the best available open source to achieve this purpose. There are example classes, compress.c and uncompress.c which almost does everything related to zipping and unzipping